# Resetting Passwords for Organizational Unit

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to use powershell to reset all passwords to a specific organizational unit. I have tried many different ways to get it to work but it still won't output a result. What am I missing? Is it the script or the results that I have incorrect? Help would be appreciated. CODE:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$users = get-aduser -filter * -properties Name, PasswordNeverExpires |
             where {$_.passwordNeverExpires -eq "true" } |
             select-object Distinghuishedname,name,enabled

$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "NewP@$$wOrd" -force

Foreach ($user in $users)
{ 
    Get-ADAccountPassword -NewPassword $password -Rese
}
 
$Results = foreach($user in $users){
    Set-ADAccountPassword -NewPassword $password -reset
}

$Results
```

Comment: There is no cmdlet with name `Get-ADAccountPassword` in the AD Module.

Comment: Should I use something else to get the passwords for the accounts? Or is it something that should be imported?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "get the passwords for the accounts".

Comment: My apologies. What I am trying to do is reset passwords for all users in an Organizational Unit and then output those results to show it was done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can reset the password for all users which's *Password Never Expires* is set to `$true`.

References for **`userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=65536`**:

- [LDAP Syntax Filters](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx)
- [LDAPWiki](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Active%20Directory%20User%20Related%20Searches)

Since [`Set-ADAccountPassword`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/set-adaccountpassword?view=windowsserver2022-ps) doesn't produce any [**Output**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/set-adaccountpassword?view=windowsserver2022-ps#outputs), you can use `-PassThru`:

> Returns an object representing the item with which you are working. By default, this cmdlet does not generate any output.

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText 'NewP@$$wOrd' -Force
$param    = @{
    LDAPFilter = "(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=65536)"
    SearchBase = 'OU=myOU,DC=goes,DC=here'
}

$results = Get-ADUser @param |
    Set-ADAccountPassword -NewPassword $password -Reset -PassThru

$results | Format-Table
```

Comment: Can I ask what the ldap filter is? Never seen that before. I’m still learning all of this so any help you can give to elaborate would be helpful. Sorry to add more to this but I like to understand things like this especially when I don’t know.

Comment: @MikeBlevins `-LDAPFilter` is a parameter that accepts LDAP Syntax for filtering. Works the same as `-Filter` but different syntax. The value used in this case is to find all user's which's `PasswordNeverExpires` is `$true`